# Llenar un arreglo con el método random y ordenarlo con el algoritmo de la burbuja

Tags: java

Espero y me puedan ayudar con un problema, estoy haciendo un ejercicio de la burbuja ya tengo programado la ordenacion de dicho metodo, solo que quiero llenar un array con 200 numero aleatorios con el metodo random, pero no se como hacerlo, miren, este es mi codigo:

```
    package metodoordenamientoburbuja;

    /**
     *
     * @author Cyberkof
     */
    public class burbuja200 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            OrdenamientoBurbuja();
        }

        static void OrdenamientoBurbuja() {
            try {
                int aux;
                int[] arregloBuble = new int[200];


                for (int i = 2; i <= arregloBuble.length; i++) {
Aqui ya no se que ondas---->arregloBuble[i]= (int)( Math.random() * 200);
                    for (int j = 0; j <= arregloBuble.length - i; j++) {
                        if (arregloBuble[j] > arregloBuble[j + 1]) {
                            aux = arregloBuble[j];
                            arregloBuble[j] = arregloBuble[j + 1];
                            arregloBuble[j + 1] = aux;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioofbE) {
                System.out.println("Error de indice");
            }

        }

    }
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor.

Quedo atento a sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Nota: Usé este algoritmo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero inicializa el arreglo con numeros random y despues lo ordenas.

Answer (score 2):

mis sugerencias son estas: El llenado se soluciona haciéndolo por separado, mas no mientras lo ordenas; y ese método burbuja esta mal implementado, aquí te dejo mi propuesta de solución.

```
    static void OrdenamientoBurbuja() {
        try {
            int aux;
            int[] arregloBuble = new int[200];

            // llenado
            for (int i = 0; i < arregloBuble.length; i++)
                arregloBuble[i] = (int)(Math.random()*200);

            // ordenamiento
            for (int i = 1; i < arregloBuble.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arregloBuble.length - i; j++) {
                    if (arregloBuble[j] > arregloBuble[j + 1]) {
                        aux = arregloBuble[j];
                        arregloBuble[j] = arregloBuble[j + 1];
                        arregloBuble[j + 1] = aux;
                    }
                }
            }

            // imprimirlo
            for (int i = 0; i < arregloBuble.length; i++)
                System.out.print(arregloBuble[i] + " ");
            System.out.println("");

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioofbE) {
            System.out.println("Error de indice");
        }

     }
```

Unos tips extras a la pregunta, como estás aprendiendo java, sería bueno si te esfuerzas en ser mas riguroso en cuanto a sus convenciones, como por ejemplo, los nombres de los métodos siempre inician con minúsculas, y no dejar de lado los modificadores de acceso (public, protected y private).

Comment: Hola amigo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, y si tienes muchisima razón se me paso usar el camelCase en el nombre del metodo y los modifcadores de acceso como tal, la logica si la tengo, el problema aqui no sabia como llenar, solo otra cosa, por que en la parte del ordenamiento es un poco diferente en la inicialización, por ejm yo me base en el algoritmo que está en wikipedia y veo que tu lo tienes diferentes, podrias explicarme por favor eso? gracias, quedo al pendiente, buena vibra.

Comment: Edité mi pregunta y puse el algoritmo que usé de wikipedia para el ordenamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Para llenar el arreglo debes revisar bien la estructura `for` que tienes, tienes un error en el valor inicial de la variable `i` y luego en la cantidad de veces que se ejecuta el ciclo `for`. Debería ser:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arregloBuble.length; i++) {
            arregloBuble[i]= (int)( Math.random() * 200);
    }
```

De esta forma, comienzas con `i=0` y se repite hasta `i = 199`, es decir, 200 veces. Con esto cargas todo tu arreglo con valores aleatorios entre 0 y 200.

Comment: Podrian de alguna manera mostrarme un ejemplo en base a mi codigo por favor?, lo que pasa es que nunca he hecho esto, y solo es llenar el arreglo y ya lo demás se encargaria de hacer el ordenamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo subdividir tu código en [métodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html). Esto te ayuda a ti, a entender más cómo funciona el flujo de ejecución, te permite detectar problemas mucho más rápido, y además es más legible.

- `ordenamientoBurbuja(int[] arregloBubble)` recibe un arreglo de enteros, que modifica según el algoritmo
- `printArray(int[] arregloBubble)` recibe un arreglo de enteros, e [imprime sus elementos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-)
- `main(String[] args)` ejecuta el programa principal, haciendo uso de los métodos creados anteriormente.

Como ya fue mencionado, debes crear un arreglo antes de procesarlo. Puedes usar la clase [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html), de la siguiente manera:

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(minimo,maximo).limit(cantidad).toArray();
```

### Burbuja200:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class burbuja200 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arregloBuble = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0,500).limit(200).toArray();

        System.out.println("Arreglo inicial \n");
        printArray(arregloBuble);

        ordenamientoBurbuja(arregloBuble);

        System.out.println("\nArreglo ordenado\n");
        printArray(arregloBuble);

    }


    private static void printArray(int[] arregloBubble) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arregloBubble));
    }

    private static void ordenamientoBurbuja(int[] arregloBubble) {
        try {
            int aux;
            for (int i = 2; i <= arregloBubble.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= arregloBubble.length - i; j++) {
                    if (arregloBubble[j] > arregloBubble[j + 1]) {
                        aux = arregloBubble[j];
                        arregloBubble[j] = arregloBubble[j + 1];
                        arregloBubble[j + 1] = aux;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException  e) {
            System.out.println("Error de indice");
        }
    }

}
```

### Salida:

```
Arreglo inicial 

[160, 115, 282, 237, 93, 166, 141, 207, 319, 376, 130, 381, 470, 312, 113, 132, 269, 375, 456, 26, 336, 448, 286, 191, 222, 213, 353, 489, 227, 308, 286, 437, 453, 86, 120, 100, 135, 333, 221, 281, 119, 416, 368, 228, 237, 74, 315, 323, 177, 494, 86, 130, 20, 182, 235, 311, 254, 467, 372, 72, 27, 258, 109, 334, 253, 386, 69, 235, 163, 154, 344, 413, 253, 298, 493, 255, 404, 165, 108, 328, 143, 489, 499, 423, 438, 5, 351, 142, 387, 136, 326, 143, 445, 187, 162, 318, 206, 28, 427, 239, 485, 493, 386, 230, 78, 84, 128, 177, 107, 80, 217, 445, 342, 26, 342, 268, 367, 397, 231, 269, 215, 355, 331, 15, 389, 438, 458, 349, 187, 16, 45, 199, 102, 9, 444, 135, 417, 68, 478, 110, 224, 3, 169, 44, 24, 63, 172, 393, 15, 483, 480, 98, 279, 244, 307, 427, 75, 498, 447, 272, 444, 23, 133, 68, 325, 383, 399, 496, 276, 129, 205, 332, 96, 361, 485, 351, 315, 328, 498, 487, 235, 315, 376, 431, 375, 16, 155, 111, 256, 316, 196, 457, 243, 102, 263, 43, 374, 189, 487, 375]

Arreglo ordenado

[3, 5, 9, 15, 15, 16, 16, 20, 23, 24, 26, 26, 27, 28, 43, 44, 45, 63, 68, 68, 69, 72, 74, 75, 78, 80, 84, 86, 86, 93, 96, 98, 100, 102, 102, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 115, 119, 120, 128, 129, 130, 130, 132, 133, 135, 135, 136, 141, 142, 143, 143, 154, 155, 160, 162, 163, 165, 166, 169, 172, 177, 177, 182, 187, 187, 189, 191, 196, 199, 205, 206, 207, 213, 215, 217, 221, 222, 224, 227, 228, 230, 231, 235, 235, 235, 237, 237, 239, 243, 244, 253, 253, 254, 255, 256, 258, 263, 268, 269, 269, 272, 276, 279, 281, 282, 286, 286, 298, 307, 308, 311, 312, 315, 315, 315, 316, 318, 319, 323, 325, 326, 328, 328, 331, 332, 333, 334, 336, 342, 342, 344, 349, 351, 351, 353, 355, 361, 367, 368, 372, 374, 375, 375, 375, 376, 376, 381, 383, 386, 386, 387, 389, 393, 397, 399, 404, 413, 416, 417, 423, 427, 427, 431, 437, 438, 438, 444, 444, 445, 445, 447, 448, 453, 456, 457, 458, 467, 470, 478, 480, 483, 485, 485, 487, 487, 489, 489, 493, 493, 494, 496, 498, 498, 499]
```